# refresh fragement after button press

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an android app that l am busy with but ran into a small problem. I am trying to refresh/restart my fragement after saving data by the use of the save button but l am getting the following err:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setNextAnim(int)' on a null object reference

here is my code in the button:

```
    save1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Util.displayMessage(getContext(),"Saving");
        String textToStore = contact1.getText().toString();
        String textToStore2 = contact2.getText().toString();
        String Url = "/gps/savetaxiroutes/"+imei+"/"+textToStore+"/"+textToStore2 +"/"+ sendNotification.toString()  ;

        AllContacts fragment = (AllContacts) 
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.thelayout2)

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .detach(fragment)
                .attach(fragment)
                .commit();
        mPopupWindow.dismiss();
    }
    });
```

this is how the code is structured in my save button method.

Comment: Are you trying to refresh the fragment UI after saving data?

Comment: the error clearly saying you are calling setNextAnim(int)  with null object

Comment: @Sarath yes l am trying to refresh the fragement UI after saving data

Comment: Try to update the UI manually or use data binding, instead of detaching and attaching the fragment for the purpose of UI update.

Comment: @Sarath, it not work as l though it would but l got a solution from another post here on stack overflow after over an hour of research:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295798/how-do-i-redirect-a-fragment-to-new-fragment

Answer (score -1):

Please read your error carefully and post related code where you using `setNextAnim()'`or starting Fragment

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setNextAnim(int)' on a null object reference
```